# Does JPA allow mapping over multiple target entity in @OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I have two child entity, both share the same parent class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
class Child1 extends Parent {
    
    private Integer child1Attr;
}

@Entity
class Child2 extends Parent {

    private String child2Attr;
}
```

And the `Parent` is supposed to be the "many side" of the `@OneToMany` relationship, something like this:

```
@Entity
class MyClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Parent> allChildSet; // <- hibernate throws exception
}
```

Is there a way to allow `allChildSet` accept either `child1` or `child2` class, since they share the same parent class? Something like this:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = {Child1.class, Child2.class}) // <- not allowed, it only accept one single class
private Set<Parent> allChildSet;
```

I'm not sure if such feature is possible from the database or ORM's point of view. If not possible, creating a `@Transient` field, I assume, is the best way to workaround. Any comment or answers are appreciated.

Comment: Are both child entities in the same table?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't know if we can map two different entity to the same table in the first place : ( , anyways I'd like to hear your suggestion.

Comment: That is definitely possible. Look at [inheritance](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#single-table). The answer to your question depends on how you implement the mapping

Comment: @XtremeBaumer OK, after some digging, it turns out, Single Table strategy is perfect for me. Thank you for the direction!